# FOLDERID_RoamingAppData equivalent in linux

Tags: c++, linux, redhat

I'm working to port some windows applications to Linux. I find it difficult to port the changes that are related to finding `SHGetKnownFolderPath` equivalent in Linux. I'm interested to find out how to detect the path based on the current user.

I stumbled upon this [link](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdg-user-dirs/tree/xdg-user-dir-lookup.c) while surfing but I'm not sure how to exactly match the windows folders with Linux.

Comment: I don't think Linux has an AppData folder. Most programs store their data in $HOME/.nameofprogram

Comment: should it be under `$HOME/.config/nameofProgram`. is this same for `appdata, localappdata, and progdata`. Please confirm.

Comment: On Linux there isn't really a place you "should" put files. Any Linux system will have similar files in several different places. `$HOME/.config/nameofProgram` is as good as any.

Comment: You "should" put config files in `$HOME/.config/yourapp` (envvar `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`) and other user data in `$HOME/.local/share/yourapp` (envvar `$XDG_DATA_HOME`) if you want to follow the XDG BaseDir Spec: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SHGetKnownFolderPath equivalent API in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37178010/608639)